# Two mutually exclusive parts of an if...else if ....else statement in C are coming up. What am I missing?

Tags: c, if-statement

Just tried to write a program (in C) where the computer picks a random number between 0 and 9, and the user keeps guessing until they get it.  I wrote is as an if...else if...else statement, and for some reason, no matter what the input is, the else statement always comes back.

For example, if I input '2', the program will say both "Oof, nice try.  But try again!" AND "You need to enter a digit!" which is supposed to be the output when you enter some random character like 's' or '@' or something. If I input 's', it will say "You need to enter a digit!" twice.

I'm *guessing* that my loop statement is badly formatted.   But I'm not sure what's wrong with it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>


int main(){

int q = rand() % 10);

char g ='\0';

printf("I'm thinking of a number from 0-9.  Guess what it is!\n");
LOOP:
scanf("%c", &g);
if (isdigit(g) && g == q){
    printf("Wow, you got it right!  Congratulations!\n");
}
else if (isdigit(g) && g != q){
    printf("Oof, nice try.  But try again!\n");
    goto LOOP;}
    
else{
    printf("You need to enter a digit!\n");
    goto LOOP;
};
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You have to convert the string to a number

Comment: The `%c` format will also process the newline character `\n`. That's why you get two outputs. The `scanf` function is not very suitable for parsing arbitrary line-based user input. You should use `fgets` to get a line and then parse it using `sscanf` or `strtol`.

Comment: This is not a very nice application for the `goto` language construct. You should use a `while` loop here instead.

Answer (score 0):

isdigit returns true of g is the ascii representation of a number ie. it checks for ascii codes between 0x30 and 0x39. g is already a number so the isdigit call is not required. scanf reads from stdin and converts it to a number. You should change the %c to %d in scanf and check the scanf return code to ensure a valid number was read. You will also need to check the range of the input is that c is between 0 and 100.